# python plotly colorbar for opacity

Tags: python, plotly, transparency, opacity, colorbar

I have a figure with multiple traces in it with different opacity and same color(green). The lines in my plot are overlapping, therefore I need some opacity of the lines, which than indicates another level of data. Now I want to add a colorbar, which goes from low opacity green to high opacity green. And I want to configure the labels to be words, for example high & low.

```
fig = go.Figure()
for i in list:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.loc[i]['x'], y=df.loc[i]['y'], name=i,
                   line=dict(color='forestgreen', width=2), opacity=df_Transparency.loc[i][0]))
fig.show()
```

Everything I found only works for only the color or for matplotlib.
["python matplotlib legend for opacity"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509315/python-matplotlib-legend-for-opacity) is an example is how it is done in matplotlib.

I want something similar like this:
[image: I want something similar like this.]]

And I tried with marker dict, but doesn't work as well.

```
marker=dict(
        size=5,
        color='forestgreen',
        colorbar=dict(
            title="Colorbar"
        ),
    )
```

Does someone know if it is possible to do it and how?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use

```
colorscale=["rgb(0,255,0)","rgb(255,255,0)"]

colorscale=colorscale,
```

Comment: If this commands does not work look here https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/

Comment: That will not work for me, because I have lines overlapping and therefore I need transparancies. and basicaly I just want a legend or colorbar for the different opacity levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the colorscale colors with `'rgba(red, green, blue, opacity)'` so, for you case:

```py
colorscale=['rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.0)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)']
```

which corresponds to going from full transparent to full opaque green.